# How do I express partial function application in Typescript 3.x in a type-safe way?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient, partial-application

I'm working on an Angular codebase that does some standard postprocessing on most API calls. This is done in a service class that wraps `HttpClient.get()` etc. in methods that pipe the returned observable through a bunch of intercepting methods.

To my dismay this is done using the pattern:

```
public get(url, options?) {
  const method = 'GET';
  return this._http.get(url, options).pipe(
    map((resp: any) => {
      console.log(`Calling ${method} ${url} returned`, resp);
      return resp;
    }),
    catchError(err => {
      console.error(`Calling ${method} ${url} failed`, err);
      throw(err);
    }),
  );
}
```

which annoys me, because the options parameter has a fairly hairy type the exact shape of which is important for TypeScript's overload resolution and determines the return type of the call.

I'm trying to figure out a less copy-pastey, typesafe way of wrapping the call, but I can't figure out how to capture the type of the options parameter.

What I have so far is:

```
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  response: any;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    const httpClientGet = this.method('get');

    const response = this.call('get', 'https://example.com/foo/bar');

    response.subscribe(
      data => this.response = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2),
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => this.response = err.error
    );

  }

  call<T>(
    method: keyof HttpClient,
    url: string,
    handler: <TObs extends Observable<T>>(partial: (options?: any) => TObs) => TObs = (_ => _())) /* HOW DO I GET THE CORRECT TYPE OF OPTIONS HERE? */
    : Observable<T> {

    const u = new URL(url);
    console.info(`Calling ${method.toUpperCase()} ${u.pathname}`);

    const result = handler(this._http[method].bind(this._http, url)).pipe(
      map((resp) => {
        console.log(`Calling ${method.toUpperCase()} ${u.pathname} returned`, resp);
        return resp;
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.error(`Calling ${method.toUpperCase()} ${u.pathname} failed`, err);
        throw err;
      })
    )

    console.info('Returning', result);
    return result;
  }

  method<TMethod extends keyof HttpClient>(name: TMethod): HttpClient[TMethod] {
    return this._http[name];
  }
}
```

That is:

- I know I can capture the signature of the method I'm calling on `HttpClient` by passing its name as a string literal to a method correctly, hovering over `httpClientGet` gives me the overloads for `HttpClient.get()`
- `call()` is the wrapper function that does the sameish interception as the original, but passes `HttpClient.get()` with the URL already partially applied using `Function.bind()` to an optional callback.
- The role of this callback is to provide the value of the `options` parameter to from the HttpClient methods if the caller wants to.

Where I'm lost is figuring out what the right construct is to tell TypeScript that the parameters of the `partial` callback should be the parameters of the corresponding `HttpClient` method, *except* the first (`url`) parameter. Or some alternative way letting me do this in a type-safe fashion, i.e. autocomplete and overload resolution should work correctly if I do:

```
this.call('get', 'https://example.com/foo/bar',
  get => get({
    // options for `HttpClient.get()`
  })
);
```

Stackblitz link for a runnable example of the above: https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpclient-partial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone with a knowledge of angular can flesh this out or give a more targeted answer, but I'm going to address this question:

> tell TypeScript that the parameters of the `partial` callback should be the parameters of the corresponding `HttpClient` method, except the first (`url`) parameter.

If you are trying to strip the first parameter off a function type, this is possible in TypeScript 3.0 and up:

```
type StripFirstParam<F> = 
  F extends (first: any, ...rest: infer A)=>infer R ? (...args: A)=>R : never
```

So for your `call()` method I'd imagine it looking *something* like this:

```
declare function call<M extends keyof HttpClient>(
  method: M, 
  url: string, 
  handler: <TO>(
    partial: (
      ...args: (HttpClient[M] extends (x: any, ...rest: infer A) => any ? A : never)
    ) => TO
  ) => TO
): void;
```

where I've intentionally left out the return type of `call` and the supertype of `TO` that you apparently already know how to deal with.

The important part is that `args` rest parameter, which is inferred to be the same as the arguments of `HttpClient[M]` with the first parameter stripped off.  That should give you the hints you expect when you call `call()`:

```
call('get', 'https://example.com/foo/bar',
  get => get({
    // hints should appear here
  })
);
```

Anyway, hope that helps point you in the right direction.  Good luck!

Comment: I've since stumbled on this and it moved me onwards alas in the direction of an even deeper swamp that I'll have to turn into its own question or a few. (The return type actually does not quite work, because HttpClient returns something different in an overload based on the value of `options`, and I'm starting to have doubts what I want can actually work without full on macros.) That said this addresses my question as stated and if nobody else comes up with something much better I'll acccept it.